# Kotlin keeps saying my return type is wrong

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to return a specific Fragment but Kotlin keeps saying PlusOneFragment and BlankFragment are not Fragment

Here is my method in my MainActivity:

```
private fun  getHomeFragment(): Fragment {
    when (navItemIndex) {
        0 -> return PlusOneFragment()
        1 -> return BlankFragment()
        else -> return PlusOneFragment()
    }
}
```

And thats my  class definition:

```
class PlusOneFragment : Fragment() {…}
```

What do I have to do to fix that?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: You probably have different Fragments imported in your files. Check that you're using the one from the support library everywhere.

Comment: It was what zsmb13 said, ty such a stupid problem

Comment: How can I set the problem as answered or solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the comment from @zsmb13 is more correct if my first answer is not the real solution. He said:

> You probably have different Fragments imported in your files. Check
>   that you're using the one from the support library everywhere.

Here's what he is talking about. There are actually several different versions of Fragment easily accessible to Android developers, [one in the support package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) and [one in the standard libraries](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html). It's easy and quite common to get these confused. I've done it myself, more than once. If you import one of these in one file and import the other in another file the error message you will get can be confusing, something about Fragment is not a Fragment. Go through your imports and make sure you are importing the same Fragment class everywhere.

Comment: Like I wrote under @zsmb13 comment, that was the problem. In Java you usually get a proper warning about that, But in Kotlin that was not the case

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin, when is an expression which has a return value. Here is how you could change your function using this knowledge:

```
private fun getHomeFragment(): Fragment {
    return when (navItemIndex) {
        0 -> PlusOneFragment()
        1 -> BlankFragment()
        else -> PlusOneFragment()
    }
}
```

However, you may choose to use it as a statement as follows (very similar to a Java switch statement):

```
private fun getHomeFragment(): Fragment {
    var result
    when (navItemIndex) {
        0 -> result = PlusOneFragment()
        1 -> result = BlankFragment()
        else -> result = PlusOneFragment()
    }
    return result
}
```

Also, looking at your logic, since anything other than 1 for navItemIndex returns a PlusOneFragment you could simplify this to an if (which is also an expression in Kotlin), as follows:

```
private fun  getHomeFragment(): Fragment {
    return if (navItemIndex == 1) BlankFragment() else PlusOneFragment()
}
```

or even

```
private fun getHomeFragment(): Fragment = if (navItemIndex == 1) BlankFragment() else PlusOneFragment()
```

Comment: Good answer, but his initial try should work because then `when` expression is exhaustive, and he has a `return` in every branch.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that you can return when()
Thats actually really nice, but the problem was different versions of fragment and my code actually worked after I changed that